# How to show Reactor marble diagram in quick documentation?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm new to IntelliJ Ultimate edition and I found that others can see the marble diagram of Reactor just like this
[image]

... when they hover methods.

But I can only see this (just some texts, without any diagram picture):
[image]

Is there any option for enabling to render the diagram?

This is my IntelliJ version.
[image]

Comment: Have you downloaded sources?

Comment: Check this option: https://i.imgur.com/eQOY37f.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Shift+A and search and select "Download sources and documentation" as showed in the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uBIj.png)

Comment: Please enter an image description

Answer (score 1):

Open the method documentation by Ctrl clicking the method.
Then choose "Download sources" option at the top of the Editor screen.
Once the sources are downloaded, you should be able to see the diagrams.